# Number of Tweets and Likes for any URL?

Tags: facebook, twitter, feed, digg

I'm building a cool app that needs to check the number of "tweets", "shares" and "diggs" each URL in a feed has an then arrange them according to the number of "tweets" etc...

Any ideas on how this can be done? It shouldn't be that hard, but I cant figure it out =)

Checkout www.babblr.me , they have a similar solution. How did they do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Digg is pretty much dead these days compared to what it used to be, just so you know.

Comment: You might want to ask on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

If you need to know the number of tweets take a look the [tweet button](http://twitter.com/goodies/tweetbutton).